# setVisible not always in operation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `LinearLayout` and a `Button`, in layout I have a `SeekBar` and when click button I show or hide `LinearLayout`, I used `View.GONE` and `View.Visible` to hide and show.

It work in many devices but when I test it in Note Edge or cool pad It does not work.

What is happening here?

```html
 rlFont = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rlFont);
        ivFont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ivFont.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.top_a001).getConstantState())) {
                    ivFont.setImageResource(R.drawable.top_a002);
                    rlFont.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    rlFont.requestLayout();

                } else {
                    ivFont.setImageResource(R.drawable.top_a001);
                    rlFont.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    rlFont.requestLayout();

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Francesc  Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not clear about the getconstantsState, why do you use that as a comparator? What is your intention here?

Comment: I want first click it show and second click it hide. Initial I set imageresource for ivFont is top_a001 and first click I check it if imageResoure is top_a001 I will show and set image resource for it is top_a002 and the second is the opposite

Comment: The way you do it is too complex. Use a boolean mFirstTime set to true, in the click lisener if it's true, you change the image and set it to false. If it's false, you do your other logic.

Comment: yep, I tried it and wait results

Answer (score 1):

This can solve your problem, with this is possible to toggle your button.

```
boolean isClicked = false;     
    rlFont = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rlFont); 
            ivFont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!isClicked) {
                        ivFont.setImageResource(R.drawable.top_a002);
                        rlFont.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rlFont.requestLayout(); 
                        isClicked = true;

                    } else { 
                        ivFont.setImageResource(R.drawable.top_a001);
                        rlFont.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        rlFont.requestLayout(); 
                        isClicked = false;
                    } 
                } 
            });
```